# OpenVPN CA Certificate creation error

Tags: openvpn, chmod

When doing ./build-ca I'm getting a weird error and I cant find any information about it, been stuck with this error for hours. I'm doing it as SU and SUDO and neither work.

This is the error I'm getting:

chmod: cannot access `ca.key': No such file or directory

Hope someone can help me, it's getting frustrating now.

Thanks <3

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are in the wrong directory.

From http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#pki

> If you are using Linux, BSD, or a unix-like OS, open a shell and cd to
>   the easy-rsa subdirectory. If you installed OpenVPN from an RPM or DEB
>   file, the easy-rsa directory can usually be found in
>   /usr/share/doc/packages/openvpn or /usr/share/doc/openvpn (it's best
>   to copy this directory to another location such as /etc/openvpn,
>   before any edits, so that future OpenVPN package upgrades won't
>   overwrite your modifications). If you installed from a .tar.gz file,
>   the easy-rsa directory will be in the top level directory of the
>   expanded source tree.

If all else fails, [install xca](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/) and follow [this guide](http://www.carbonwind.net/VPN/XCA_OpenVPN/XCA_OpenVPN.htm).